# Gradients for 2D geometric shapes

Tags: math, graphics, geometry

I've been generating islands using a combination of Perlin noise and radial gradients -- as outlined in [this awesome Reddit answer](http://www.reddit.com/r/gamedev/comments/1g4eae/need_help_generating_an_island_using_perlin_noise/). It's working pretty well, but obviously the islands are all circular in shape, and I'd like more variety.

I was wondering if there is a general method of converting equations for geometrical shapes into equations for gradients. Eg. an equation that is to its shape what Euclidean distance is for a circle. Is this possible? Is it obvious?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Defining an implicit surface for a geometric shape, or the [Level Set](http://mathinsight.org/level_sets) ([wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Level_set)), is basically what you are asking for. For example, the implicit surface of a circle with radius R is

f(x,y) = x^2 + y^2 - R^2

Note that when f(x,y) = 0, that defines the surface of the circle. When f(x,y) < 0, then x^2 + y^2 < R^2, which means the point (x,y) is inside the circle centered at the origin. Finally f(x,y) > 0 means the point (x,y) is outside the circle.  In order to create an image out of this, you would need to iterate over every pixel and evaluate f(x,y), while finding the min and max value, then scale the whole image to have a range between 0 and 1.

This would technically not give you distance. The circle is a special case because the equation for it (x^2 + y^2) **is** the squared distance function from the origin. This does give you the effect you are most likely looking for your problem  - negative inside, positive inside (or vice versa), while the magnitude is scaled w.r.t. to the distance of a given point to the surface.

For any equation you come up with for a geometric shape, you need to get all the terms on one side to form f(x,y).  For example, take x*y = log(x). That can become x*y - log(x) = 0, so f(x,y) = x*y - log(x).